# how to calculate percentage in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
    function splitAmount(uint256 amount) private {
        a1.transfer(amount.div(2));
        a2.transfer(amount.div(2));
    }
```

I've seen other threads on this but I feel like over complicate things. With this code the amount is evenly split between a1 and a2 with division by 2.

How would one do something like a 80/20 split with the same code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

80% is the same thing as

- multiply by 80, and then divide by 100

  as well as
- multiply by 4, and then divide by 5

```
a1.transfer(amount.mul(4).div(5)); // 80% of `amount`
```

You can simplify the 20% in the same way:

- multiply by 20 and then divide by 100

  which is
- multiply by 1, and then divide by 5

  which is simply
- divide by 5

```
a2.transfer(amount.div(5)); // 20% of `amount`
```

Comment: Would then "a1.transfer(amount.div(100).mul(80));" be the same thing?

Comment: @Alessandro Yes for `amount`s divisible by 100... If you had `amount` value 50, the `.div(5).mul(4)` would return 40 as expected. But the `.div(100).mul(80)` would return 0, because at first it calculates `50 / 100` (which results in the unsigned integer 0), and then `0 * 80`.

Comment: what if you want a decimal percentage value? Example 0,001%

Comment: @R01010010 Then you can divide by a larger number. As per your example, if you want to get 0.001% of `amount`, then you calculate `amount.div(100000)`